# ALternative method for python urllib or requests in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, url

I am using python urllib to get an image from an URL.

```
img=Image.open(urllib2.urlopen(URL))
```

What is the alternative method to do this in plain Javascript?

Comment: Browser side or server side ?

Comment: client side@brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Then it's just a matter of creating an `Image()` object (or retrieving an existing one from the dom) and setting it's `src` attribute to your URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ajax call:

**Edit because of comment:**

```
var img = new Image(); 
$('#your-image-container').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "GET",
        async: True,
        success: function(in_img) {
            img.src = in_img;
            $(this).append(img);
        },
    })
}
```

That is a direct alternative.
You should also consider that in javascript, you can simply do:

```
 $(function(){
       $("#your-image-container").attr("src", URL) 
 });​
```

and you will have the image loaded in the #your-image-container!

Comment: I need to store the image data in a variable so that I can later manipulate it.@John Moutafis

Comment: I have changed the code to suite your needs, check it out :)

Comment: Thanks @John Moutafis

Comment: No problem mate :)